# Highlighting 'bool' used in Java, within Emacs

Tags: java, emacs, syntax-highlighting

I switch back and forth between Java and C++ in my current job, and as a result I tend to use 'bool' in Java instead of 'boolean'.  I program in Emacs, which highlights 'bool' in a declaration the same as any other type, so I don't tend to catch the error until compile time.

Is there any way to get java-mode to highlight 'bool' for me so that I can catch the error while I'm writing the code?

Comment: I also switch a ton between Java and C++ and while I'm a vi guy, my workflow all happens in eclipse.  This is great because it has syntax support for both c++ and java and you can turn on emacs commands which are built into eclipse.

Comment: As much as I am a fan of emacs, it's useless for any significant Java programming. If I need to do *actual* editing, I'll use emacs. If I need to do Java development... no way, no how.

Comment: There is [eclim](http://eclim.org/) for java programming in emacs/vim.

Comment: @DaveNewton - with JDEE installed, i am quite happy programming java in emacs.  you have the power of emacs text editing (e.g. hippie expansion) combined with useful things like import handling from JDEE.  setup the eclipse compiler in flymake (using JDEE) to get on-the-fly errors/warnings...  perfection!

Comment: @jtahlborn It's acceptable, but does not approach the functionality offered by a modern IDE. Without strong refactoring support it's just not helpful for anything of any size or complexity. I <3 Emacs, but it's just not the tool for the job.

Comment: @DaveNewton - never understood the argument for "strong refactoring support" (JDEE does have something like that, but i've never used it).  personally, i find emacs' various regex based search and replace tools and grep/sed to be more than sufficient (i've generally worked on codebases ~200k loc).

Comment: @jtahlborn There's absolutely no (reasonable) comparison to be made between that, and actual refactoring support.

Comment: @DaveNewton - well, like i said, it works just peachy for all the refactoring i do, and i am not shy about refactoring.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add this to your .emacs:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 'java-mode
        '(("\\<bool\\>" . font-lock-warning-face)))
```

Comment: Thanks, that almost works.  Emacs seems to color it red right after I type the keyword but sometimes reverts to normal coloring when I complete the function or variable declaration that 'bool' appears in.

Comment: I've changed the regexp slightly, does that help?

Comment: you probably need to force it to "override" any other highlighting.  try changing `font-lock-warning-face` to `(0 font-lock-warning-face t)`.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest is perhaps

```
M-x highlight-regexp RET
\_<bool\_> RET
font-lock-warning-face RET
```

You can certainly add this to the `java-mode-hook` too.  Downside is, of course, this method provides no syntactic checking and will highlight also in strings and comments...